# How can I create a POST request using retrofit 2 with multiple params

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to use this method

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult method(int param0, int param1, int param2)
```

Using Retrofit 2 but I don't know hot to do, I tried with this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("method")
Call<data> method(@Field("param0") Integer param0
   , @Field("param1") Integer param1, @Field("param2") Integer param2);
```

But I had the 404 code

Comment: 404 status code is for unknown / invalid URL. check if you are calling a valid URL.

Comment: Yep I'm calling for the valid URL but the problem that I think is on how I send the data with Retrofit @Sanoop

Comment: Did you tried @Path instead?

Comment: @Sanoop can you give me an example of how use Path in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST("method/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}")
Call<ResponseBody> method(@Path("p1") int param0, 
                          @Path("p2") int param1, 
                          @Path("p3") int param2);
```

Just try this and let me know in comments

Comment: Thank you for your help! It doesn't work, but helps me to find how to solve it, I used @Query to send the data, but I don't know why I had to send it in the url if the method is POST